# How to integrate Logout functionality in dropbox iPhone app?

Tags: ios, api, dropbox, logout

I am working in Drop box application in iPhone, Using Dropbox_SDK to develop this application, I have upload and download a file from my dropBox account, its working good.
Then I tried to Log Out the dropbox account in iPhone, but i didn't know that integration,
How to do this?

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    UIButton *Logout =[[UIButton buttonwithtype:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
    Logout.frame=cgrectmake(10,10,100,50);
    [Logout setTitle:@"Log Out" Forstate:UIControlStateNormal];
    [Logout addTarget:self action:@selector(Method)ForcontrolEvent:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [Self.view addsubview:Logout];
}

-(void)Method
{

    //Logout Integration

}
```

Comment: Did you try [[DBSession sharedSession] unlinkAll];

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Used this command to Log out Drop box account in iPhone application

```
 [[DBSession sharedSession] unlinkAll];
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't logout,you can only cancel the request with `- (void)cancelAllRequests;` .and clear cache of your device . You will be automatically logout .